# A detail in the proof of trace theorem of Sobolev space in Evans

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In Partial Differential Equations 2ed of Lawrence C.Evans, there is a detail in the proof of trace theorem of Sobolev space where I have some doubt.

[image]

I think the underlined formula use Green formula or integration by part. This need the integrand continuously differentiable. If $p>1$, it is right, but if $p=1$, I don't know why it is right.

Comment: Isn't it assumed that $u\in C^1(\overline U)$? They might weaken the condition on $u$ later.

Comment: Yes, $u \in C^1$, but why $|u|$  is also $\in C^1$?

Comment: I see. You are just using fundamental theorem of calculus on the $x_n$ direction, the theorem is true if the function involves is absolutely continuous. Now $|u|$ is Lipschitz, thus it's still ok.

Comment: I know, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Since $u\in C^1(\overline U)$, $|u|$ is Lipschitz, hence absolutely continuous. The fundamental theorem of calculus applies to such functions: the value at $x_n=0$ is related to the integral of $x_n$-derivative in the usual way (the other boundary term is zero since $\zeta$ is compactly supported).

(From a comment by [John Ma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462020/a-detail-in-the-proof-of-trace-theorem-of-sobolev-space-in-evans#comment2977365_1462020))

Comment: I rescue this post as I am at the same step and don't really understand the equality. If I understand well it is used the Lebesgue Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with the almost everywhere derivable function $|u|^p$. But Why is the minus there?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with "the value at $x_n=0$ is related to the integral of xn-derivative in the usual way"?

Comment: For anyone who finds this question: Refer to Brezis "Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and PDE" for an alternative proof. He utilizes the function $t|t|^{p-1}$ which is indeed $C^1$.